# How to find out what cell phones support wallpapers

Tags: wurfl

I have Adobe Device Central, and there I can see which phones support wallpapers, but I cannot export this list to another designer who needs to create the different sizes for my cell phone wallpapers.

I know WURFL and its varying flavours can tell me this, but it seems I cannot do a search for only phones that support wallpapers and their screen sizes. Does anyone know of another method of returning these hundreds of phones without painstakingly going through all of them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Using the wurfl java api (>1.0.x), the `WURFLUtils` interface, you can abtain the full device list and filter them by wallpaper support. Take a look at [javadoc](http://dev.wurflpro.com/maven/wurfl/apidocs/net/sourceforge/wurfl/core/WURFLUtils.html)